# Retrieve an email-id from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an page where I am embedding email-id of the user into the url and sending him mail 
now I want to extract the email from the url and match the value with the database. My question is how do I retrieve that email from that url?

```
string url = "http://localhost:3063/user/Authenticate-Users.aspx?"+emailfield;
```

this is the url...

Comment: Hi, you should use a WebRequest to access your url and download the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to normal standards, the parameters in query string should have names. So your url should be converted to this instead:

```
string url = "http://localhost:3063/user/Authenticate-Users.aspx?email="+emailfield;
```

Then in your code, simple use this syntax to get the value:

```
var emailadress = Request.QueryString["email"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only thing coming after the `?` in the URL, you can use such code:

```
string emailID = (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) ? Request.QueryString[0] : "";
```

While adding name is indeed better practice it's not vital.

Answer (score 0):

To get values from the url:

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys()) 
{
     var values = Request.QueryString.GetValues("emailfield");
     if (values != null)
     {
         var id= Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the URL to:

```
string url = "http://localhost:3063/user/Authenticate-Users.aspx?emailID="+emailfield;
```

and the code @Koen suggested. If the emailfield is not an integer but an actual email address, you could use

```
string email = Request.QueryString["emailID"];
```

If changing the URL is not a choice, then you could check every query string

```
foreach (string email in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    // TODO: do something with email
}
```